# Proving $I+J=R$ in a PID

Tags: ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a PID. Let $I$ and $J$ be two nonzero ideals such that $I\cap J=IJ$. How to prove that 
$I+J=R$?

So far, I have only been able to show that $I$ and $J$ will be contained inside different prime ideals (hence maximal ideals, since in a PID prime ideals are maximal):

Let $\langle p\rangle$ be a prime ideal which contains both $I$ and $J$. Then $I=\langle ap\rangle$ and $J=\langle bp\rangle$ for some $a,b\in R$. Then $abp\in I\cap J=IJ$. As $abp\in IJ$ we have $abp=cabp^2$ for some $c\in R$. Then $cp=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: If $I = (0)$, then $I\cap J = I = IJ$ for any ideal $J$, and $I + J = J$. Are you sure this is the statement you want? Do you want instead *if* $I + J = R$, *then* $IJ = I\cap J$?

Comment: See question number 11, Part 2. https://math.indiana.edu/graduate/tier1/Algebra/2009-01-Algebra-T1.pdf

Comment: It would be preferable for you to include what you are able to show by simply applying the definition of PID to the nonzero ideals $I$ and $J$ (and $IJ$, for the sake of completeness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $I + J\neq R$, then there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq R$ with $I + J\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$.